# Create user on order status completed action hook in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-data

I am trying to create a new user within the **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`** hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_woocommerce_order_status_completed', 10, 1 );

function custom_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order_id )
{
    $password = wp_generate_password( 16, true );
    $user_id = wp_create_user( 'usertest@gmail.com', $password, 'usertest@gmail.com' );
}
```

`$user_id` returns an actual ID. It appears to create the user but when i look at the backend the user is not there. I even check the database for the user id and it's not there.

If i call the same function on the action **`woocommerce_after_register_post_type`** it creates the user.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses Woocommerce [`wc_create_new_customer()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_new_customer.html#37-117) dedicated function instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'action_on_order_status_completed', 20, 2 );
function action_on_order_status_completed( $order_id, $order ){
    $password    = wp_generate_password( 16, true );
    $user_name   = $user_email = 'usertest@gmail.com';
    // $user_name   = $user_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    $customer_id = wc_create_new_customer( $user_email, $user_name, $password );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks that seems to do the trick. Really strange the standard function doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function name does not match the one call within your hook:

`custom_woocommerce_order_status_completed`

Comment: Sorry had to change function names when posting here and forgot to update. The code does have the right function referenced. I have updated my question. Thanks for pointing it out. Any other ideas?